# canvas keyboard focus through iframe (resists tab-switch)

Tags: javascript, iframe, keyboard, html5-canvas

I have a canvas in `iframe.html` which gets loaded in `index.html`. Within `iframe.html`, the game gets keyboard input via `window.addEventListener('keypress', press, false);`.

This works great. However, if at any time the user presses `tab`, the iframe loses focus, and can't get it back (even if you click back on the iframe/canvas). Mouse input continues to work- but keyboard is ignored.

One solution I've found is putting this in index.html:

`setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("content").contentWindow.focus();},100);`

(`"content"` is the `id` of the iframe).

The problem with this is: 1. it's constantly running this BS code, and 2. I may-or-may-not have control of what goes in index.html in the future (I might be hosting this on third party sites).

So I assume there's a solution that doesn't constantly execute re-focusing code, and doesn't require *any* code within the iframe-containing web page.

Note- I'm totally fine if "tab" loses focus- but there needs to be a way for the user to re-give the iframe focus.

Comment: Can you just add a keypress event listener that runs `event.preventDefault();` if the keypress is a tab?

Answer (score 0):

Within the iframe document, can you add an event listener on the `document` that calls `event.preventDefault();` on `keydown`? Also, in the same way, could you add a `click` event listener that calls `focus()` on whatever you want focused? If it's not a naturally focusable element, add `tabindex="1"`.

There may be some feature of iframes that I'm not considering, but that seems like it should work.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  document.querySelector('div').focus();
});

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
  if (e.key === 'Tab') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
}

div:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0">I'm bad for accessibility!</tabindex>
```